# How do I get AWS Batch to run jobs using private repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr, aws-batch

I'm trying to run a batch job on a container with AWS Batch using Fargate spot instances. What I have accomplished so far:

- Upload image to ECR via CI pipeline into a private repository
- Successfully ran job on ECS Fargate cluster

  - Created proper ECSTaskExecutionRole (as described in AWS docs)
  - Did not enable private repository authentication (the ECSTaskExecutionRole has "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"... in my mind that suffices to fetch a token and pull the image. I also don't see the reason to store secrets somewhere when I can handle everything with IAM permissions... am I wrong?)
  - I ran the cluster in a

    - dedicated VPC with 2 public subnets
    - an IGW (Outbound allow all, inbound allow HTTP, HTTPS and SSH)
    - enabled auto-assign public IPv4 and DNS

Now I am actually trying to run the job with AWS Batch on Fargate spot instances. So I basically use the same setup but with a different compute environment (can't use my default one for some reason). And what I'm seeing is this error:

```
ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: execution resource retrieval failed: unable to retrieve ecr registry auth: service call has been retried 1 time(s): InvalidParameterException: Invalid parameter at 'registryIds' fail...
```

Now, I also tried to run a generic Hello World job created with the AWS Batch Wizard which results in this error:

```
CannotPullContainerError: inspect image has been retried 5 time(s): failed to resolve ref "docker.io/library/amazonlinux:latest": failed to do request: Head https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/amazonlinux/manifests/latest: dial tcp 18.214.230.110:4...
```

I tried to identify the differences between the task created in the ECS console and the task created in the Batch console. The only difference I could find was that the latter uses the "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.22" next to 1.18 and 1.19. The task created with ECS is not using 1.22 ...

I already checked out the other answers regarding that topic, but couldn't solve the issue so far...

Comment: Same issue, how did you resolve it?

Comment: One problem I had was that the network configuration did not stick when set via UI. Which is no problem because I am using terraform anyway but still strange. For now I keep running my batch jobs on containers directly managed by ECS with Fargate. It works well. I will definitely try running them on spot instances some time in the future... but for now I don't have an answer...

Comment: if you are pulling image you need to ENABLE Auto-assign public IP. I was missing this and got the same error as yours.